# X509Certificate2.Verify() method, validating against revocation list and performance implications of it

Tags: .net, x509certificate, x509certificate2, certificate-revocation

I want to validate the X509 certificate. And I thought to go for [X509Certificate2.Verify()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify.aspx) method.

However, the documentation does not tell anything about what all things it verifies.

1. Please direct me to some documentation which provides details of this method.
2. Does Verify() method verifies the certificate against revocation list? If yes, what if online list is not available or network is not available?
3. Are there performance implications when you validate certificate against revocation list?

Comment: It works according to RFC5280 as I know (http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5280/?include_text=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100403/do-we-need-root-certificate-installed-on-the-machine-always) question to understand Verify method more.
2. Yes, Verify() method checks if the certificate using which it's called is revoked or not.
3. There is no big performance hit but yes, it takes little longer time to verify if the certificate is revoked.